# I'm learning C# in vs2008 while vs2010 is available. Am I missing something?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

that is my question.

Beacause I'm learing C# in vs2008, I was asking to my self if i'm missing something not learning in vs2010.

I won't touch WPF/Silverlight for a while, with C#, ASP.NET and SQL Server I have a lot of fun for a while.

well, that's my question, I'm getting vicious or missing something using vs2008 ?

Answer (score 7):

The main thing will be the new .NET 4 and C# 4.0 features.

However, as you are still learning it won't hurt to concentrate on the .NET 3.5 and C# 3 features first. Though you should be looking to move to VS 2010 at some point.

Answer (score 2):

you will miss the new c# 4.0 features ...
take a look on : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383815.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of cool features in .NET 4.0, but I think 3.5 is a great place to start. You can get experience with Linq and WPF/Silverlight (eventually), and all of these skills will ease you right into 4.0 when the time comes. Don't delay too long though; they push out new versions somewhat regularly.

Answer (score 0):

Both WPF and silverlight are supported in VS2008.

By using VS2008 you are basically missing any features that are only available in [C#4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_4.0) and [.NET 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#.NET_Framework_4), and also some other minor IDE enhancements.

.NET 3.5 has enough for you to learn (WCF, WPF, Silverlight, Entity Framework, ...) for the moment, but at the same time if it doesn't hurt you to upgrade you might as well run the latest.  It's good to know a history anyway of what the language used to have vs what it has now.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, let's see. ASP.NET 4.0 with all the goodies alrady installed - not SO much. The really much better development environment - maybe (I persnally will not touch 2008 ever again - finally I have multi monitor support). The better SQL Server R2 integration - possibly, but if you have to ask like that you possibly don't use the version with the database project type anyway.

So, at the end - no. But then the question is - why not just update?

Btw., Silverlight is something to really look at. At leasst the moment you need osmething like client side charts. I find it, and the OData protocol implementation, very valuable ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine. You are missing out on .NET 4. But .NET 3.5 has so much to learn, and all of it is still relevant in the .NET 4 world that you won't waste anything. .NET (and C#) are big, really big. So in a sense, you might even be better off by taking it in chunks.

And for what it's worth, the XAML designer in VS 2010 is so unbearably slow that you're almost better off in a sense :) (That is, if you decide to pursue Silverlight or WPF).

Comment: And I am finding VS 2010 to be buggy enough that I am already anxious for SP1. 2008 is much more stable.

Comment: What bugs are you seeing?  Are you using any third party addons?

Comment: I have no third party add ons so far.

Occassional 2010 just locks up with no hope for recovery, I have to kill it from the task manager. And also occassionally it crashes and asks me if I'd like to restart it.

Comment: But the worst bug I am seeing is an "infinite loop" of debug sessions. I start a debug session, and then some accidental keystroke during this session (any keystroke that is not legal during debugging, like attempting to edit something) puts me in a state such that once I stop the debug session, VS immediately starts another one. It doesn't do this every time, I'd say once out of every 10 debug sessions on average.

Comment: I am also seeing a fair amount of painting issues with the new WPF based controls. Just different situations can cause a document or whatever to be partially black. Forcing it refresh somehow (resize it) fixes it. Not that big of a deal.

Comment: And here is an example of the black areas: http://i.imgur.com/VIcAM.png